# Браузер получает исходный код?

Tags: веб-программирование, cgi

Получит ли браузер исходный код CGI-приложения при запросе к этому приложению по URL?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Он получит только выхлоп этого приложения.

Конечно же это при условии, что сервер настроен на выполнение CGI приложений. В противном случае сервер может отдать запрашиваемый ресурс "как есть"